# Crashed: twilio_pj_pool_alloc

Tags: ios

My App got crashed yesterday, and i am unable to understand the logs where it get crashed, please if any one can get me out of this.

> `Thread : Crashed: com.twilio.TCCommandHandler.commandQ
>   0  Bhaasha                        0x1006b1604 twilio_pj_pool_alloc (pool_i.h:59)
>   1  Bhaasha                        0x10065ccec -[TCMakeCallCommand run] (TCCommands.m:95)
>   2  libdispatch.dylib              0x199b717b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
>   3  libdispatch.dylib              0x199b71770 _dispatch_client_callout`

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/agentsim/Symbolicator to find out were your app crashed.

Comment: Were you able to figure out why this crashed?

Comment: Having the same crash. Any idea @Prashant or @Guven?

Comment: @MárioCarvalho I am lost on this one as well. Twilio has very poor support as well so couldn't get anywhere there either. I have decided to switch to their new SDK.

Comment: @Guven Your client name has special characters like à,é,í ... ?

Comment: @MárioCarvalho Referring to the twilio username? In any case, I don't think  the client names had any special characters.

Comment: @Guven I'm referring to client_name encoded inside CapabilityToken. In server-side code is what they call 'Identity'

Comment: @MárioCarvalho That one doesnt have any special characters for sure. Why did you ask? Was the the problem? This happened to me only after the Swift 3 switch.

Comment: @MárioCarvalho I have put an answer for this one; that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this one out. It actually doesn't have to do with Twilio; Twilio libraries seem to be somehow emit the error. Of course, the Twilio support team had absolutely no comment/idea on this one.

It seems to be related with the Microphone usage description that came with iOS 10. If you update your .plist with the microphone usage description text, the error doesn't occur anymore.

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your description goes here.</string>
```

For more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html.